# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on net.viralpatel.hibernate.Employee.department

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to `hibernate`. I developed `OneToMany` relation example, but I see following example. **Please help me how to solve below error?**

```
INFO: Bind entity net.viralpatel.hibernate.Employee on table EMPLOYEE
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on net.viralpatel.hibernate.Employee.department references an unknown entity: net.viralpatel.hibernate.Department
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.viralpatel.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    at net.viralpatel.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at net.viralpatel.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on net.viralpatel.hibernate.Employee.department references an unknown entity: net.viralpatel.hibernate.Department
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(AnnotationConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at net.viralpatel.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    ... 2 more
```

I developed code so far:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="employee_id")
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name="cell_phone")
    private String cellphone;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="departmentId")
    private Department department;


    public Employee(){}

    public Employee(String firstname, String lastname, String phone) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.birthDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.cellphone = phone;
    }
  // setters and getters 
}
```

Department

```
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Long departmentId;
    @Column(name="DEPT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public Long getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(Long departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Department department = new Department();
        department.setDepartmentName("Sales");

        Employee emp1 = new Employee("Nina", "Mayers", "111");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Tony", "Almeida", "222");

        department.setEmployees(new ArrayList<Employee>());
        department.getEmployees().add(emp1);
        department.getEmployees().add(emp2);

        session.save(department);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you annotate `Department` with `@Entity`?

Answer (score 0):

Mark Department class as Entity with @Entity annotation.